# Почему при миграции БД через flyway sequence не обновляется?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, flyway

Приведу простой пример:
Используемая БД - PostgresSQL.
Используемый стек: Spring Boot + Hibernate + FlyWay

@Data

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long bookId;

    //....
}
```

Вот, генерируемая hibernate'ом таблица

```
create table if not exists books
(
  book_id bigserial not null
    constraint books_pkey
      primary key,
  language_id bigint
    constraint fksp7ty25kndaxyfrgkrloo1dd8
      references author
);
```

Пример sql запросов для импорта:

```
INSERT INTO "public"."books" ("book_id", "author_id") VALUES (1,  2);
```

После миграции данных через flyway sequence не обновился.
Т.е. у меня должно быть более 200 объектов, а sequence индекс показывает 1.

```
SELECT last_value FROM books_book_id_seq;
last_value 0
```

При этом например, для другой сущности, которая была инициализирована java скриптом индекс отображается корректно.
Проблема чем-то похожа на эту:
[Ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35011338/hibernate-5-assigning-id-that-already-exists-in-db-as-preinitialization-org-sp)

И зачем hibernate генерирует sequences, если GenerationType.IDENTITY ?
В чем заключается моя ошибка?

**Обновлено**

Попробовал другое - сменил GenerationType.SEQUENCE
hibernate создала hibernate_sequence Но также изменила DDL таблицы на (bigserial -> bigint):

```
create table if not exists books
(
  book_id bigint not null
    constraint books_pkey
      primary key,
  language_id bigint
    constraint fksp7ty25kndaxyfrgkrloo1dd8
      references author
);
```

В любом случае при миграции через flyway значение не инкрементируется. Максимум могу вручную подправить это значение.

Ну а так как значение в sequence некорректное, то вот Exception - DataIntegrityViolationException

Заранее благодарю за ответы!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Почему при миграции БД через flyway sequence не обновляется?

Тут есть недопонимание, как работает `serial`/`bigserial` тип в `postgres`.

Это тип, который, в случае если вы не задали значение при создании записи, сгенерирует значение из `sequence`. Если же значение для поля было явно задано (как в случае миграции, которую вы создали), то оно вставляется, как есть, а sequence при этом **не модифицируется**.

Исправить это можно одним из трех способов. При создании записей в миграции можно:

1. не указывать `book_id`, чтобы сработал механизм автоматической генерации
2. либо вручную использовать `sequence` привязанный к полю `book_id`
3. либо вручную обновить `sequence` после вставки всех записей

Рассмотрим эти варианты

#### Не указывать book_id

```
INSERT INTO "public"."books" ("author_id") VALUES (2);
```

Если нужно сослаться, на только что сгенерированный идентификатор это можно сделать так (на примере с автором):

```
INSERT INTO "public"."author" ("name") VALUES ('somebody');

INSERT INTO "public"."books" ("author_id")
SELECT currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('books', 'author_id'));
```

#### вручную использовать sequence

Честно говоря, сильного смысла вариант не имеет, но для полноты картины включаю его тоже. Выглядеть запрос будет так:

```
INSERT INTO "public"."books" ("book_id", "author_id")
SELECT nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('books', 'book_id')), 2;
```

#### вручную обновить sequence после вставки всех записей

```
SELECT pg_catalog.setval(
         pg_get_serial_sequence('books', 'book_id'),
         (SELECT MAX(book_id) FROM "public"."books") + 1);
```

> зачем hibernate генерирует sequences, если GenerationType.IDENTITY

Тут все не совсем так. `sequence` создает не `hibernate`, а `postgres`.

`IDENTITY` означает, что поле автоматически сгенерируется БД, если оно не задано. Т.е. `hibernate` при создании новой сущности в БД просто не передает это поле.
И это ответственность БД сгенерировать значение автоматически.

В `postgres` типы с автогенерацией значения - `serial`/`bigserial`. То что внутри используется `sequence` - это деталь реализации автоматической генерации в `postgres` (ведь он создается автоматически и пользователю в большинстве случаев не нужно о нем заботится - поле автоматически генерируется и это то, что нужно). Именно поэтому, этот  `sequence` нигде не фигурирует в маппинге `hibernate`.

А для `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` нужно явно указать в маппинге, какой `sequence` используется. При создании новой записи `hibernate` выполнит запрос к БД, чтобы сгенерировать значение для поля, используя указаный в конфигурации поля `sequence`. И потом использует это значение непосредственно при выполнении `INSERT`.

Когда вы сменили тип генератора на `GenerationType.SEQUENCE`, то в этом случае `hibernate` создает другой тип поля в БД - `bigint`, т.е. тип без автогенерации, потому, что этим вы явно указали использовать `sequence`.

Comment: Благодарю за подробный ответ! Много чего полезного узнал. К сожалению, первый вариант (не указывать book_id) не подходит, так как там не одна таблица, а несколько и они связаны друг с другом OneToMany &  ManyToOne и мне явно нужно указать какая строка таблицы связана со строкой другой таблицы.  Третий вариант с обновлением sequence после вставки всех записей тоже понятен. Не совсем понял второй вариант - использовать вручную sequence. Может ссылочку подскажете, где можно прочитать про это? Заранее спасибо)

Comment: Проблема со ссылками на вставленные записи частично решаема. @OrkhanHasanli дополнил ответ.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Выручили)